# embed {{link-to}} inside html <button> tag

Tags: html, ember.js

How to embed link-to inside html button tag ?

This is what i have tried -

```
<button {{link-to "posts.show" post}}>
  Show
</button>
```

Getting Uncought Error: There is no route named

```
embercli@model:post::ember506:6
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the tagName of the link-to to button instead.

```
{{link-to 'posts.show' post tagName='button'}}
  Show
{{/link-to}}
```